# Has the criteria for the audits changed?

Tags: support, review, review-audits

On Meta.AskUbuntu.com we have these two new questions:

[Should voting to close a correctly closed question for the right reason really be considered failure?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13804/should-voting-to-close-a-correctly-closed-question-for-the-right-reason-really-b)

[Failed audit - unclear really?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13799/failed-audit-unclear-really)

From those, I am wondering if the audits criteria for selecting a question has changed - or is it just bad luck?